# 220 volt ac to 12 v dc converter without voltage regulator

Tags: transformer, filter, converter, remote-control, bridge-rectifier

I want to design Additional RC Filter. My input is 220V AC and I want to observe 12 V DC output. I am designing 100 Hz with a full-wave bridge rectifier. My question how can I find the output of rectifier's Vdc and Vrms values?
[image]

Comment: Are you, by any chance, hoping to make a 12 V DC power supply? You do realise that the low voltage side will be live?

Comment: How much current do you want at 12VDC?

Comment: This is a dangerous setup.  As you probably expect, your voltage depends very much on the load.  Adding a divider R_A/(R_A+R_B) where R_A=15.6xR_B=R_L/10 is safer.  So if R_L is 10k, then choose R_A=1k and R_B=15.6k.     R_L//R_A=0.9k.  Voltage=220V.0.9/(15.6+0.9)=12V .  Without a load, the voltage is 220V*1/(15.6+1)=13.2V .

Comment: As others pointed out, this circuit can be very dangerous because it has no isolation. I strongly recommend you use a topology with a transformer to provide isolation between the AC side and the output.

Comment: `My question how can I find the output of rectifier's Vdc and Vrms values?` By doing circuit analysis at the output. You need to use transformer at the input side for your own safety. We don't want you to die. Also RC filter waste power. Use transformer 220Vrms primary input with secondary 15Vrms output -> Full-Bridge-Rectifier -> LC filter -> LM7812 instead for a simple regulated safety project.